# how to get type from a partially closed generics

Tags: c#

**-- EDITED --**

But when I got a complex generic:

```
class Class<T> : Interface<T, List<T>>
{
    // ...
}
```

**how can I get `typeof(Interface<, List<>>)`?**

// `typeof(Interface<, List<>>)` has compile error

I really do not want to use `typeof(Class<>).GetInterfaces()[0]`.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the exact purpose of this code, you already have type T in generic, use that directly

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I try to use `DependencyInjection`.

Comment: Your purpose is then mapping, to invoke the correct concrete implementation by DI framework at run-time. Is it a DI binding issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass all the generic parameters exactly how they should appear in your interface.

```
        int i = 1; // just for example, any suitable type
        var type = i.GetType();
        var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        var intfType = typeof(I1<,>).MakeGenericType(type, listType);
```

**EDIT**

If I finally understood OP correctly - you cannot do this. Type can be either open or closed. You can define generic types (classes and interfaces) using a mix of other generic and non-generic types, but it is possible specifically for defining types. You cannot construct partially closed or partially modified generic type in runtime from those definitions. To do what you want, you need to introduce another interface which will define only one generic parameter and then operate with it:

```
        interface GenericInterface<T1, T2>
        {
        }

        interface ListInterface<T> : GenericInterface<T, List<T>>
        {

        }

        class Class1<T> : ListInterface<T>
        {
            // ...
        }

        var blah = typeof(ListInterface<>); // this is the exact interface that Class1 implements
```

Comment: when I use dependency injection, it require pass a generic type so it can dynamically build the closed type.

Comment: @Cologler for the code you have written, he has provided a correct example, is the issue related to DI binding

Comment: @MrinalKamboj but I am ask `typeof()` for generic type, not a closed type. It use for build the DI container, not get the instance from DI container.

Comment: @Cologler, I have perfectly answered your question which did not say a word or contained any hint about using DI. ;) You should have asked it correctly saying that you want it in DI because for that the answer would be completely different.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov your `intfType.ContainsGenericParameters` will return `false`, but all my expected type (like `typeof(Class<>).GetInterfaces()[0]`) .`ContainsGenericParameters` will return `true`. It is little different.

Comment: @Cologler, then please re-word your question so that it would be quite clear what exactly you're asking. In this case it would be what is it you want to get from DI. I personally cannot infer it from your last comment. It looks like I did answer the question you've asked, but the question you've asked is not the question you actually wanted to ask.

Comment: @Cologler, no :( It still says nothing about what it has to do with DI. To inject a dependency you need a) DI container which will be injecting dependency; and b) something where to inject that dependency to - usually, it is a class constructor or sometimes class property. There's nothing of that kind in your question.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov DI just the one of scenarios.

Comment: @Cologler, I updated my asnwer. But for the future reference - the question should be formed such that other people would not have to guess what you're asking and what it has to do with this or that, otherwise everyone will just skip your question.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov you are right. partially closed generics type is not a type. now I am making a generic type tree to resolve this problem.